# Java Bean & JSF formatting List of Dates

Tags: jsf, javabeans, netbeans-8

I'm fairly new to JSF, Java Beans, and JPQL. I have 2 nested c:forEach tags. The first loops for each DISTINCT Date, the second for each each 'timeslot' on that date.

```
<c:forEach var="d" items="#{bean.listedDates(1)}" >
     #{d.date}   <!-- this displays '11' -->
    <ui:decorate template="template for day" />
    <c:forEach var="item" items="#{bean.listedTimeslots(1, d.date)}">
        <ui:decorate template="template for time-slot row" />       
    </c:forEach>                                    
</c:forEach>
```

**bean.java - listedDates**

```
public List<Date> listedDates(int idPass) {        
    List<Date> dateQueue = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT l.date FROM table1 l WHERE l.id = :id")
    .setParameter("id", idPass)
    .getResultList();

    System.out.println("DATES DISPLAYED BELOW");
    System.out.print(dateQueue);
    return dateQueue;
}
```

**Console**

Info: DATES DISPLAYED BELOW

Info:   [Wed Feb 11 00:00:00 GMT 2015, Wed Mar 11 00:00:00 GMT 2015, Sat Apr 11 00:00:00 BST 2015]

However, #{d.date} displays '11'. And this error occurs in regards to passing d.date into listedTimeslots.

*Cannot convert 11 of type class java.lang.Integer to class java.util.Date*

I need to format my list of dates from [Wed Feb 11 00:00:00 GMT 2015] to [YYYY-MM-DD] (Which is also how its displayed in the database), can anyone give me any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: did you try JSF converters ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried `<f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-mm-dd">` around the second forEach but no data is displayed.

Comment: how about casting your result set, i don(t think you are receiving dates from the db.

Comment: I am receiving data from the DB. The displayed '11' refers to the [Wed Feb **11** 00:00:00 GMT 2015]. To be sure, I just modified data, and the error message updated too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you address your bean property.

When you use `#{d.date}` you are telling your bean to access a property of the `java.util.Date`instead of the whole date value you are expecting.

The property you are accessing here is `date` through `getDate()` which returns the number of the day of the month which has `int` as a type according to the Java 6 documentation of `java.util.Date` which I think you are using to compile and run this code.

To solve this problem you will need to change the following EL :

Use `#{d}` instead of `#{d.date}`

Your code should look something like this :

```
<c:forEach var="d" items="#{bean.listedDates(1)}" >
  #{d}   <!-- changed-->
  <ui:decorate template="template for day" />
  <c:forEach var="item" items="#{bean.listedTimeslots(1, d)}">  <!-- changed-->
     <ui:decorate template="template for time-slot row" />       
   </c:forEach>                                    
</c:forEach>
```

***References:***

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: And modified to `<c:forEach var="item" items="#{bean.listedTimeslots(1, d)}">` and it works perfectly, thank you very much man. Drove me mad for hours haha

Comment: it worked ? (i'm trying to replicate your full code.)

Comment: Yep, perfect. I didn't need to specify `#{d.date}`. Thanks again!